# How to use Object.bsonsize in MongoDB Stitch Functions code?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

Is there any way to use Object.bsonsize in MongoDB Stitch Functions code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object.bsonsize is not currently supported in Stitch.